# Match every character except for a particular string in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, pattern-matching

I want to match every character except for when encounter a particular string and then stop there.

Here is an code-based explanation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$string="111s111ab1s";

#-- greedy match
$string =~ /^(.*)s/;
print "$1\n"; # prints 111s11111

#-- ungreedy match
$string =~ /HOW TO/;
print "$1\n"; # prints 111
```

Make a simple example of yours --if you need a better one.

Answer (score 3):

```
#-- ungreedy match
if ( $string =~ /^(.*?)s/s ) {
    print "$1\n"; # prints 111
}
```

The /s flag is necessary if your string contains newlines; without it, `.` doesn't match a newline.  It's always a good idea to check whether your regex matched; if you don't, `$1` may be left over from some other successful regex match.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to add a question mark (`?`) after the `*` quantifier. What this means is look for any character (*except a linebreak*) and find (`0` or more of them) until you get to an `s`. Once you specify the question mark, you're stating (**don't be greedy..** as soon as you find an `s`... stop, you're finished.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "111s111ab1s";

print $1 if $string =~ /^(.*)s/;  # 111s111ab1
print $1 if $string =~ /^(.*?)s/; # 111
```

Answer (score 1):

I would search for anything not an s, like this ...

```
$string =~ /^([^s]*)s/;
```

Answer (score 1):

As [regular-expressions.info documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) says, you can use operator laziness:

> Laziness Instead of Greediness
>
> Lazy quantifiers are sometimes also called "ungreedy" or "reluctant".
>   You can do that by putting a question mark behind the plus in the
>   regex. You can do the same with the star, the curly braces and the
>   question mark itself.

So, your **greedy** star operator in your regex is:

```
$string =~ /^(.*)s/;
```

While **ungreedy** or lazy would be:

```
$string =~ /^(.*?)s/;
```